# How to disable "Contact a Board Administrator"?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

The page `/forum/memberlist.php?mode=contactadmin` leads to this page that allows a guest to spam.

**How to completely disable this "Contact a Board Administrator" feature in phpBB 3?**

[image]

---

Sample spam message:

> Hello Administrator,
>
> The following is an e-mail sent to you through the administration contact
>   page on "xxx".
>
> The message was sent from a guest who specified the following contact
>   information:
>   Name: Barnypok
>   E-mail address: jfvynms4281rt@hotmail.com
>   IP Address: 188.143.x.x
>
> Message sent to you follows
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> zd9hNf *Link deleted.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to go to *ACP (Admin control panel) > Contact page settings > Enable contact page > Disabled.*

[image]